# Flatlist maintainVisibleContentPosition causes instant crash on iOs

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have an app with only this component:

```
function TestComp() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item)}
            data={[0, 1, 2, 3]}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <View>
                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>
            )}
            maintainVisibleContentPosition     <--- Causes crash
        />
    );
}
```

The program crashes immegiately, throwing the error:
`Exception thrown while executing UI block: - [__NSCFBoolean objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11bfcae48`.

The crash disappears when I remove the maintainVisibleContentPosition props (but I need it).

I am on `react 16.11.0`, using `expo sdk 38.0.0`.

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Looks like you logged a ticket? https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9757. I haven't been able to understand why either. Are you in managed mode?

Comment: Yes, I am in managed mode. The issue is also happening in production so I am not sure it is due to Expo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because React is expecting you to define the minimum visible position even if it's zero. So instead of just putting maintainVisibleContentPosition, try using

```
maintainVisibleContentPosition={{
     minIndexForVisible: 0,
  }}
```

Comment: Indeed, somehow I missed this information. It did stop the crash, but unfortunately, it does not maintain the content position for me. The list still jump went content is added to the top of the list (or bottom if inverted) :(

Comment: It seems to not work the very first time you prepend data (jumps), but to work on the subsequent ones (maintains visible content).

Answer (score 0):

[maintainVisibleContentPosition](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#maintainvisiblecontentposition) here is official docs

the App is crashing due because `maintainVisibleContentPosition` is aspecting a object

try this

```
maintainVisibleContentPosition={{
     minIndexForVisible: 0,
  }}
```

here is demo: https://snack.expo.io/@nomi9995/flastlist-fix-crash

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
        <FlatList
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item)}
            data={[0, 1, 2, 3]}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <View>
                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>
            )}
            maintainVisibleContentPosition={{
              minIndexForVisible: 0,
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: Oh, is this new? I can't believe I could have missed that.

Comment: @RyanPergent no it is old. you can use this prop from official docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#maintainvisiblecontentposition